# position relative is not properly working for a button placement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button which is just below the textare and there is another button just above the textarea, due to some reason i cannot change the loction of the top button but on the screen i want that the button aobe the screens should be besides the button where the second button is, i have been able to bring it but when i type something in textarea, the textarea is resized a bit and the buton position is moved, the button whcih i moved with css does not move and stays there and it  overlaps the textarea.

what i am trying here is if the second button is moved a bit, the other one should be moved along with it

here is my css and html

```css
#ApprBtn {
  position: relative;
  top: 175px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form name="form0">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <Input Type="Submit" id="ApprBtn" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" Value="Approve">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<form name="form1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea class="textareaW" name="Reason" id="Reason" cols="100" rows="5" wrap="Virtual"></textarea>
      </td>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <Input Type="Submit" id="RejectBtn" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" Value="Reject">
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

it works when i start typing in textarea and textarea grows a bit, the rejection buttons keep going down, but the approve button stays at same place, how can i move that approve btn too along with reject button, this thing is just killing me now

Comment: Do both forms have an equal parent element?

Comment: What is it that you expect will make the "Approve" button change position?

Comment: Relative positioning means relative to the container element. Since the two buttons are in different containers, they won't move together.

Comment: If you want the buttons to be next to each other, why are they so drastically far away from each other in entirely different table structures in entirely different forms?  Why aren't they simply... next to each other in the HTML?

Comment: You can put both elements in the same `<form>`, and give them different "name" attributes and a non-empty value. That way your server will see one button or the other when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

As people in the comments have already written, positioning only matters for elements that have some common parents.

I am assuming you can't refactor the HTML for some reason, but if those two forms have a wrapping div, maybe something like this could work for you.

```css
.form-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form-wrapper form,
.form-wrapper table,
.form-wrapper tbody,
.form-wrapper tr,
.form-wrapper td {
  display: contents;
}

.form-wrapper input {
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#ApprBtn {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
<form name="form0">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <Input Type="Submit" id="ApprBtn" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" Value="Approve">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<form name="form1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea class="textareaW" name="Reason" id="Reason" cols="100" rows="5" wrap="Virtual"></textarea>
      </td>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <Input Type="Submit" id="RejectBtn" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" Value="Reject">
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: but its too sparse, can we use classes to handle it, i mean input is used for other purpose too

Comment: I added a class to the wrapping div, but this is just an example. The point is that you should use a wrapping div to style the two forms. There are multiple ways to achieve that if you manage to wrap them. :)